# Error getting SQL reservations and availablity

Tags: sql

I am trying to find the rooms which are not booked from the `yyyy-mm-dd` to `yyyy-mm-dd`. I am getting the rooms which are booked technically. How to invert the result?

My reservations:

[image: This is my reservations table]

This is my rooms table

[image: Rooms Table]

```
SELECT distinct r.room_id 
FROM rooms as r 
INNER JOIN  reservations as b ON r.room_id = b.room_id
WHERE ('2021-01-20' NOT BETWEEN date_from AND date_to) 
  AND ('2021-01-07' NOT BETWEEN date_to AND date_from)
```

When I run this query, I get rooms which are booked. I want to get all the rooms which are not booked for example in this case I should be able to see 7 which is not booked between mentioned dates.

Comment: please only tag the database you are using,

Comment: You have `date_from` and `date_to` in both those tables. That query should be showing an error about ambiguous column names.

Comment: The booking info really should not be in the Room table. What happens when a second booking is made on  a room?

Comment: sorry mistakenly uploaded same photo twice. check it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following modification:

A `LEFT JOIN` was used instead to capture rooms which may not yet have a reservation. I also switched the `date_to AND date_from` to `date_from AND date_to` and added an additional clause `OR b.reservation_id IS NULL` to capture rooms that may not have been booked as yet

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    r.room_id 
FROM  
    rooms as r 
LEFT JOIN  
    reservations as b ON r.room_id = b.room_id
WHERE (('2021-01-20' NOT BETWEEN date_from AND date_to) 
    AND ('2021-01-07' NOT BETWEEN date_from AND date_to) 
 ) OR b.reservation_id IS NULL
```